# Prove that $\angle DAP=\angle CAB$ in a parallelogram $ABCD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, geometric-transformation

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, and let $K$ be on $BC$ and $L$ on $CD$ so that $BK\cdot BC=DL\cdot DC$. Let point $P$ be where $DK$ and $BL$ intersect. Prove that $\angle DAP=\angle CAB$ (angles $DAP$ and $CAB$ are equal).

I got that $ADL$ and $ABC$ are similar so it is enough to prove that $\angle LAP=\angle CAK$, but I think there is an better way to use the given statement.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByGmeK3txyClSUM5OFNoSmQ5R1E/edit?usp=docslist_api.       Here is a picture I drew, bcs I dont have a pc nearby.

Comment: see if this works. extend $AP$ to meet $BC$ at $Q.$ seems that $AKQ$ is similar to $ALC$

Comment: i have verified that the result is certainly true for a rectangle $ABCD$

Comment: For those looking to construct this figure: Take $O$ a point on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{BD}$, and consider $\bigcirc O$ that passes through $C$. Then $K$ and $L$ are the other points where $\bigcirc O$ passes through the specified edges of the parallelogram.

Comment: Well, we can just draw a ray from A forming an angle with AC equal to CAB, pick any point P on that ray, and join P with C and with B to get K and L. By the way, @Blue can you check your construction? I think it looks very suspicious. If we put the parallel translations K' and L' of K and L on the sides AD and AB, then I see a circle through BDK'L'. Those circles on C that Jack and you constructed, I don't see them.

Comment: @Pp..: Constructing from the conclusion is kinda cheating, isn't it? ;)  As for the circle: As Jack mentions, the products $BK\cdot BC$ and $DL\cdot DC$ calculate the power of points $B$ and $C$ with respect to some $\bigcirc CKL$. Such power is also equal to $r^2-d^2$, where $r$ is the circle's radius and $d$ a pt's distance from the center. With respect to a circle with a given $r$, since (by assumption) the powers for $B$ and $C$ match, their "$d$"s must match, too. That is, the center of $\bigcirc CKL$ is equidistant from $B$ and $C$: it's on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{BC}$.

Comment: @Blue I see it now. I didn't recall the relation of the power with to the distance.

Comment: @Pp..: I'm glad that made sense, even though I had mistakenly referred to point $D$ as point $C$ in my comment. :/

Comment: @Blue It is contagious, all the time I was thinking about the problem I called D, C, and had to switch it back to write it.

Comment: Where did you take this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using oblique coordinates.

> The main purpose is to show that the proof is entirely linear. This means that one can construct a synthetic geometry proof using only similarity of triangles, after drawing lines through $K,L,P$ parallel to the sides of the parallelogram.

Let's use $AB$ and $AD$ as the axes. So $A=(0,0)$, $B=(0,\ell_1)$, $D=(\ell_2,0)$ and $C=(\ell_2,\ell_1)$. Call $r:=\frac{\ell_1}{\ell_2}$.

The line $AC$ is $y=rx$.

> We want to prove that the line $y=\frac{1}{r}x$ is the locus of the points $P$. This is enough to get the conclusion.

Take a point $P:=(a,a/r)$ on this line.

Then the line from $D=(\ell_2,0)$ to $P=(a,a/r)$ is given by 
$$y=\frac{\frac{a}{r}-0}{a-\ell_2}x-\ell_2\frac{\frac{a}{r}-0}{a-\ell_2}$$

This intersects $BC=(y=\ell_1)$ at $K=\left(\left[\ell_1+\frac{\ell_2a}{r(a-\ell_2)}\right]\cdot\frac{r(a-\ell_2)}{a},\ell_1\right)$, i.e. $$BK=\left[\ell_1+\frac{\ell_2a}{r(a-\ell_2)}\right]\cdot\frac{r(a-\ell_2)}{a}$$

The line from $B=(0,\ell_1)$ to $P=(a,a/r)$ is given by 
$$y=\frac{\frac{a}{r}-\ell_1}{a-0}x+\ell_1$$
This line intersects $DC=(x=\ell_2)$ at $L=\left(\ell_2,\frac{a-r\ell_1}{ra}\ell_2+\ell_1\right)$, i.e.
$$DL=\frac{a-r\ell_1}{ra}\ell_2+\ell_1$$

Now we only need to divide

$$\frac{BK}{DL}=\frac{\left[\ell_1+\frac{\ell_2a}{r(a-\ell_2)}\right]\cdot\frac{r(a-\ell_2)}{a}}{\frac{a-r\ell_1}{ra}\ell_2+\ell_1}=r=\frac{\ell_1}{\ell_2}=\frac{DC}{BC}$$

Answer (score 1):

With knowledge of projective geometry this is pretty easy problem. 
[image]
Let $a=AB$, $b = BC$, $BK = x$ and $DL = y$. Then we have $$y= {b\over a} x$$ 
so $L$ is lineary dependent on $K$, thus the transformation $$K\mapsto L$$ from a line $BC$ to a line $CD$ is projective. This one induces new projective transformation $$DK \mapsto BL$$ from a bundle of lines through $D$ to a bundle of lines through $B$. Since clearly $BD$ goes to it self, this transformation is perspective so the intersection point $P$ describes some line.

Clearly when $K=\infty $ then $P=A$ and let $C$ maps to $E$ (so $DE = {b^2\over a}$). We see that $E$ must be on $CD$. All we have to see now is that the triangle $ADE$ is similar to the triangle $ABC$ which is simple since: $${DE\over DA} = {{b^2\over a }\over b} = {b\over a} = {BC\over BA}$$